# BeanCreationException for Session scoped bean in @async method

Tags: spring, multithreading, asynchronous, spring-session

I am stuck into a problem of accessing a session scoped bean  in async method.

My Bean definition:

```
<bean name="ABC" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="session">
<aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

My controller class has the annotation '@EnableAsync'.
I am autowiring the class with async method in controller :

```
@Autowired
AsyncWorker asyncWorker;
```

When the async method is called, it tries to get the session bean defined above by the following line of code:

```
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = context.getBean("ABC");
```

This ends up with the following error

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.ABC': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

RequestContextListener is also defined in my web.xml.

All works good when the call is synchronous.
Starting a new thread or using the Async method results in the same error.
Any help on this would be appreciated.